# Recover photos from locked Android (Galaxy S5 Verizon)

Tags: lock-screens, data-recovery

My mom passed tonight and there are some photos of her on this old phone I have. Losing them is not an option but I only have 1 attempt left on the lock code before it factory resets the data so I can't attempt that or do the Google account unlock or anything.

I read a bit about yodot or something that may be able to help, but I wanted some help from the experts before I dive in and screw it up because like I said if I mess this up I will be absolutely devastated.

I really hope you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If adb is on then you have a chance to recover data from the device.

1. Install adb and fastboot drivers in your Computer.
2. Connect your phone with an USB cable
3. Open terminal and enter `adb devices`

   4. If it shows your device then you can extract any file by entering `adb pull path/to/file`

Comment: Doesn't ADB require USB Debugging? If so, Developer Options has not been enabled on this device and neither has USB Debugging.

I heard about flashing a custom recovery ROM or something without losing the files. Is this a possibility?

Comment: I haven't tried it and I will not recommend it to you

Comment: @DanL try to boot into stock recovery and then connect it to pc. I think either adb or file transfer is possible in this state